# Is there a way to compile react components to html before build time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that takes dom elements and operate on them. It is called `pageTransition`, and it takes two `div` elements, and performs a transition animation from the one to the other.

```
function pageTransition(div1, div2){//do the transition}
```

for example i can call this function like,

```
pageTransition (document.body.querySelector("#div1"), document.body.querySelector("#div2"))
```

That is simple, but let us say I want to pass `React class components` as my `div` elements. And that isn't possible because react components are class's not html elements. One quick reminder, this react components in the end will be compiled to `div` elements with some content during build time. I know I could get around this by doing this

```
...//the react class
render(
    return (
        <div id="div1">...</div>//this will allow me to call the above function with the same parameters
    )
).
```

But I was just wondering if there was a magic way to compile this react classes before build time, so rather than giving the id's to the returned div's I was wondering if I could do something like this `pageTransition(compile(reactClass), compile(reactClass));`

Comment: check this out, hope it helps
https://medium.com/@himanshu_tanwar/build-time-html-with-react-2f122be5af29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will depend on your intended purpose for pageTransition.

However, there are three potential options you may want to look into:

1. Statically render a React component into html markup or a string: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup
2. Render two div elements in html and use a React portal to manage what is being rendered in the those divs. This could potentially replace what you are doing in pageTransition. https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html
3. Use a ref to access the DOM element that is built from the React component: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

If you explain what pageTransition does it might help me find a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an introduction to concepts I didnt know and an idea to solve my problem,